# Allow registered users post content or articles - Joomla 3

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, user

Im looking to allow users to post information on a page. I understand I can give them author rights but I only want them to be able to edit and post content on the 'Submit' page and not the other pages such as 'Home' and 'Terms'. Is there a plugin or method to do this. Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you can do this with Joomla ACL. I'm not very knowledgeable in this area, but something like [ACL Manager](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/acl-manager) may help you.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand you want to give different access to different different menus. For this,in Joomla, we use **ACL (Access Control List)** and you don't need to use any plugin or extension. Refer the link below:

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Access_Control_List_Tutorial

You can give different authorities to different users. Please have a look in the following example as well:

1. Open 'Submit' menu item in `Menu Manager > Submit`: In the right sidebar, you will find an option `Access` , set it to `Guest`. By doing this, you allow only the guest users to view the submit page .

   - Guest users are those users who are visitors of our website.
2. For `Home` and `Terms`, set the `Access option` to `Registered`. By doing this, only the registered users will see these menu items.

IN this way, you can easily restrict different users accessing different menus/pages on your website.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

No plugin is needed! Your best option is to assign the Home and Terms navigation links to single articles.

You then assign other menu items to display specific categories that you've chosen, which your users will then have the option of selecting from. When they categorize their article, it will display on the appropriate page since that page is set up to list all articles within a category.

Hope this helped!

Edit: I realized I misread your question. You can change editing permissions by assigning editing permissions on a per-category basis on the backend.

Add a link to your user menu that takes users to the article submission form, which ships with Joomla, and make sure that user permissions are set for all of your categories.